# How to stop song when click again on table view and play another song when click another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avaudioplayer

I have some songs and showing in tableview. When I press cell it's play the song. I want to stop when I touch the same cell but if I touch another cell I want to make it still playing with new song.

```
extension SoundsViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return songs.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soundsCell") as! SoundsTableViewCell
    cell.soundPicture.image = UIImage(named: "cell1")
    cell.soundLabel.text = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.playStopImage.image = UIImage(named: "play")

    if selectedItemIndex == indexPath.row {
      cell.playStopImage.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row
    playSong(song: songs[indexPath.row], selectedItemIndex: selectedItemIndex!)
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

```
func playSong(song: String, selectedItemIndex: Int){
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: song, ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer.play()
        var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presumably your `audioPlayer` is an instance variable of your view controller.

Change your playSong function to call audioPlayer.stop() before creating the new AVAudioPlayer. That should stop the previous sound.

### EDIT:

Add a function like this to your view controller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        print("Deselecting row \(selectedRow.row). Stop playing sound")
        audioPlayer.stopPlaying()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        if selectedRow == indexPath {
            return nil
        }
    }
    print("Selecting row \(indexPath.row). Start playing sound")
    playSong(song: songs[indexPath.row], selectedItemIndex: selectedItemIndex!)
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: It's adding one line of code to your playSong function. If you can't work that out you need to go back to basics.

Comment: it is not the solution. I want to stop when touch the same cell. But if i touch another cell while playing it should change with out stoping.

Comment: By the way audioPlayer.isPlaying always false ?

Comment: Keep track of which cell is selected. If the user taps the already-selected cell, call `audioPlayer.stop()`. If they change selected cells call your `playSong()` function.

Comment: How can I check the already-selected cell? I can get selected cell with "self.selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row" but how can use it in function?